# LINQ union 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a table `(T)` which has references to 2 additional tables (`A`,`B`) (both references are null-able, but there is still one filled in per row). I need union data from all 3. If row in `(T)` references `A`, then I need data from `A`, if `B`, then data from `B`. This is not a problem, but I need to project into type, where there is a collection of strings in table `A`, but for table `B` there is no (assigning `null` or `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` or `new List`... produces error). Any ideas?

Illustration :

```
(from t in context.T
join a in context.A on t.RefA_ID equals a.ID
select new ProjectionType
{
   ...
   CollectionProperty = a.Collection
}).Union(
from t in context.T
join b in context.B on t.RefB_ID equals b.ID
select new ProjectionType
{
   ...
   CollectionProperty = WHAT_SHOULD_I_PUT_THERE??? // needed because of union
})
```

EDIT:
maybe simple question would be: How to project empty collection in LINQ to Entities?

EDIT2: exception:
`A type that implements IEnumerable 'System.Collections.Generic.List...' cannot be initialized in a LINQ to Entities query.`

Comment: "assigning null or Enumerable.Empty() or new List... produces error".... what error? Can't see why that should not work. Please show the code you tried for these three possibilities and the error message you got.

Comment: @RenéVogt I cannot check it right now, but it's similar to case, when you are trying to use for example string.Join or string.Aggregate or any other function, that cannot be translated into SQL query by EF.

Comment: and what if you leave that line out completely (like only `select new ProjectionType()`)? `CollectionProperty` should then be `null` by default.

Comment: @RenéVogt as I have written, I'm doing union there - therefore both projection types has to be 1:1 and for the first table I need those values

Answer (score 0):

It seems, defining the dummy variable outside query works